# In my android studio, filter option was disappear

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

In my Android Studio, Filter Option was disappear.

In my Android Studio, there was a Filter Option like the red square in the picture below.

[image]

However, I don't know when, but the Filter Option has disappeared as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I want to see the log using "Show only selected application" in the Filter Option of Android Studio.

How do I make the Filter Options visible again?...

Note that,

I am using these versions.

- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
  Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
- Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.3.1
- Gradle Version 7.4
- Bolt Toolkit version 1.14.7

(Likewise, the Filter Option was not shown in Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.6.3, Gradle Version 5.6.4 and AGPV 4.2.2, GV 6.7.1.)

And I have the following Event Logs.

File pattern '*.log' (from 'Ideolog' plugin) was reassigned to file type 'log' by 'Bolt Toolkit' plugin.
You can confirm or revert reassigning pattern '*.log'.
Confirm reassign this pattern to file type 'log' from plugin 'Bolt Toolkit'.
Revert this pattern to file type 'LOG' from plugin 'Ideolog'.
Edit file type 'LOG'.
Edit file type 'log'.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the old Logcat if you untick
**File > Settings > Experimental > Logcat > Enable new Logcat tool window**

BTW you can keep filtering with the new version, more info here
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#logcat-search

Comment: Oh my gosh. You perfectly provided the solution I wanted. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaPdY.png)  Type **package:mine**   in  filter text - hint "Press Control + Space to see available keys" field

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#logcat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).